# How do you use <TAB> to cycle through completion suggestions with ALE?

Tags: neovim

When using [Ale](https://github.com/w0rp/ale), I'd like to use the Tab key to cycle through completion suggestions. By default, the arrow keys do it. What are the various configuration options for cycling through the suggestions as well as selecting the correct completion?

[image]

Comment: I have the same question - did you end up finding an answer?

Comment: An answer was just posted that works @vincecampanale!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Could do something like this:

```
inoremap <silent><expr> <Tab>
      \ pumvisible() ? "\<C-n>" : "\<TAB>"
```

Essentially, when you hit tab in insert mode, check whether the popup is visible, and if it is then send `Ctrl-n` (to go to the next match), otherwise send a tab.

Comment: Thanks. I also added `inoremap <silent><expr> <S-Tab> pumvisible() ? "\<C-p>" : "\<S-TAB>"` to make Shift-Tab select the previous suggestion.